# Using LEFT with LEN Turns Float Into Weird Format (e.g. 6.0871e)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 70 million rows of data with a column that contains numbers, but it's in a float format. I need to get rid of the last 4 digits of that column i.e. I need to turn this

`60871003002001
60871003002002
60871003002003`

into this

`6087100300
6087100300
6087100300`

When I run the query

`select top 3 LEFT(COLUMN, LEN(COLUMN)-4) as a from TABLE`

it returns the following:

`6.0871e
6.0871e
6.0871e`

Does anyone know why? I'm using SQL Server. There are no nulls and each number is from 12 to 15 digits long.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, divide by 1000 and turn into a decimal:

```
select cast( (col / 10000) as decimal(18, 0))
```

The problem you are facing is that the default conversion of a float to a string might sometimes be in scientific notation.